# Ubuntu workspace switch shortcut not working after update

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I have installed ubuntu 18 on my MacBook pro retina 15', and set new shortcuts to switch workspace.

For example, I have set trough system settings <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>right_arrow</kbd> to go to the below workspace, and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left_arrow</kbd> to go to the above.

However, from time to time it looks like one of the two shortcuts does not work, and I need to log out & in in order to make it work. I think some package broke out when upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to 18, but I don't know which one.

I don't have any workspace extension installed.

Thank you in advance